# Debian ssh Cannot Resolve Hostname on DHCP Server

Tags: debian, ssh, dhcp

I used to connect to my raspberry pi via ssh using the hostname of the pi and vice versa. Now that doesn't work. I can connect by using the ip address, but that changes daily and it is annoying to continually have to find it. How can I configure my computer (and pi) to do this automatically? I am using debian and I would prefer to not set up my own dns server. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a home network? What device/software is currently serving DHCP on your network? (If it's a home network, it's probably your router.)

Comment: This is my school's dns server

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for DNS?

```
nslookup `hostname`
```

The output will show you your DNS server - this is where your problem is.

Comment: I keep running into the SERVFAIL problem when I do this and try the command `host hostname.` It says "** server can't find (myhostname): SERVFAIL" I'm not sure what is wrong. I tried switching to openDNS and had the same issue, so I switched back. This is on a college campus and we don't have ipv6 here, so I disabled ipv6 ala https://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6#How_to_turn_off_IPv6 and it didn't help.

Comment: @cden Could your `/etc/hosts/` file be broken?

Comment: @cden, what does your /etc/resolv.conf say? Are you using a network manager?